# HTML to PDF in c#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, xsl-fo

I'm trying to create an application that converts a file from the HTML format to the PDF format.

The approach I am using is:

1. HTML to XHTML
2. XHTML to Formatting Object
3. Formatting Object to PDF

I'm having a bit of trouble with the whole XHTML to FO(or xsl).

Can you please tell me how to transform the XHTML to FO?

Or maybe a different approapch to the whole HTML to PDF?

Thanks, Catalin

Comment: I'd definitely buy a product that does this for you.  Not an easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use a HTML to PDF converter via shell, I am sorry I can not rememeber the name of the one I have used in the past, if you have a Google around, you should be able to find a good one.

Comment: Yes, it is a program. You use the shell command to run it from your C#

Answer (score 3):

> I have write easiest way to write html to pdf code using NRerco Pdf library which available free, Install nuget package

PM > Install-Package NReco.PdfGenerator

```
   Create HtmltoPdf()
   {
   if (System.IO.File.Exists("HTMLFile.html"))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete("HTMLFile.html");
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("HTMLFile.html", html);
    var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("export.pdf"))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete("export.pdf");
    }

    htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("HTMLFile.html", null, "export.pdf");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Searched a lot for my personal stack app project [SO2PDF](https://stackapps.com/questions/1559/so2pdf-export-questions-and-answers-to-pdf) and finally settled with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which so far is the best free tool to convert HTML to PDF. Yes I used it with c# ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the different approach. We are going to convert HTML/XML to PDF directly with 3d party tool (it has multiple preference and settings of conversion and doesn't require any external libraries).

1) Download free [HTML to PDF SDK](http://www.pdfonline.com/c%23-html-to-pdf/) from [her](http://www.pdfonline.com/c%23-html-to-pdf/) (it is easy PDF SDK)

2) Use the following code or run Action Center to customize the conversion

```
using BCL.easyPDF.Printer;

namespace TestPrinter
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         if(args.Length != 2)
            return;

         string inputFileName = args[0];
         string outputFileName = args[1];
         Printer printer = new Printer();
         try
         {
            IEPrintJob printjob = printer.IEPrintJob;
            printjob.PrintOut(inputFileName, outputFileName);
         }
         catch(PrinterException ex)
         {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
            printer.Dispose();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[Image: HTML to PDF C# API - Action Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUdpl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

here I give you one code which provide html to pdf file in .net. Install one nuget package which is the [Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore/22.2.0).

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // instantiate the html to pdf converter
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
    
    //get html file path
    var html = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\..\\index.html");

    // convert the url to pdf
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
    
    //save pdf file path
    var file = "C:\\Users\\..\\index.pdf";
    
    // save pdf document
    doc.Save(file);

    // close pdf document
    doc.Close();
}
```